How to access Azure Key Vault secrets as *configuration values transparently* in a ASP.NET Core Web App which is deployed to Azure App Services?
My question is about the C# code of reading secrets stored in the Key Vault as configuration transparently. For example currently I have this appsettings.json:
"AzureAd": {
 "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
 "Domain": "mydomain.com",
 "TenantId": "...coming from Connected Services/Secrets",
 "ClientId": "...coming from Connected Services/Secrets",
 "ClientSecret": "...coming from Connected Services/Secrets",
 "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
 "Scopes": "access_as_user"

},
In development time those secrets are configured using Services/Secrets, so the secrets are not pushed to the repo.
How can I use and configure a configuration reader in the release build, which reads those configuration values from my Azure Key Vault transparently?  In transparently I mean, the application itself is not aware where the configured secret is coming?
For example I have the statement builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd") and I would like this work transparently...
(I do know how to deploy my ASP.NET Core App to Azure App Services, how to create secrets in Azure Key Vault, and  how to give access to the deployed App Service to the Key Vault, so this question is not about those)

You could do the following.
For hierarchical Keys in the KeyVault, you can create them like:
AzureAd--Secret1
AzureAd--Level1--Secret2


Your local secrets should be configured in your
secrets.json. Right click on your project: "Manage User Secrets".

Introduce a IS_LOCAL Flag to your launchSettings.json:
 "Your project Local": {
     "commandName": "Project",
 "launchBrowser": true,
     "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5000",
     "launchUrl": "api/v2/swagger",
 "environmentVariables": {
     "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
     "IS_LOCAL": "true"                      
 }

Then in your Startup.cs or Program.cs:
  if (!env.IsLocal())
  {
      configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
          new Uri(configuration.GetValue<string>("YourKeyToAzureKeyVaultCredentials")),
          new DefaultAzureCredential());
  }

IsLocal() is an Extension:
public static class HostEnvironmentExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLocal(this IHostEnvironment _) 
        => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IS_LOCAL")?.Equals("true") ?? false;
}

And also in your Program.cs:
 services.Configure<YourConfiguration>(configuration);

YourConfiguration Class should look like this:
public class YourConfiguration 
{
    public SecretConfiguration AzureAd{ get; set; }
}

And the SecretConfiguration is just a POCO class:
 public class SecretConfiguration
 {
     public string Secret1{ get; set; }
     public string Secret2{ get; set; }
 }

Now you can transparently inject YourConfiguration Class in your services - and it will use your secrets.json in local mode or your Azure Key Vault on the server:
// When Service is Scoped
public class ServiceA (IOptionsSnapshot<YourConfiguration> configuration)
{
      public void SomeMethod()
      {
           var secret1 = configuration.Value.AzureAd.Secret1;   
      }
}


I do not see how this solution reading the hierarchical data. The appsettings.json is a hierarchical data, it has sections, and MS components like .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp() expect hierarchical configuration section data... line in my sample AzureAd config file...

Its reading hierarchical data from your appsettings.json, secrets.json and from Azure Key Vault, you just have to build YourConfiguration class respectively. When you have a level under AzureAd then you need a Property from another class which again has Properties and so on.

I´m using this solution for years and it is exactly what you have described: "...and I would like this work transparently". And this is the case. Just try it out.

and what is the syntax rule to place hierarchical data into Key Vault, it is a flat list...

You can write "AzureAd--Secret1", "AzureAd--Level2--Secret1" and so on. You can give these items a  hierarchy in the KeyVault by using "--".

many thx. That is an answer. please include this in the answer and I am going to accept it.

perfect. I will do.

Its added. Thx for accepting. :)
